# Android : How to get product details from barcode?

Tags: android, barcode

I am going to implement application in which i want to read car's VIN number and then using that VIN number i want details of that car like year and make etc.I want to capture that from camera and then use in app.
So my question is,

1. Is there any method to scan for VIN number like barcode.
2. From where to get that details.

Is there any solution, or rather is this possible?

Comment: Your question is not clear. What are you trying to do ?

Comment: ok. I just want product details from barcode i have scan.

Comment: Did you see [Zxing Barcode Scanner](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/)  ?

Comment: Thanks hardy for your interest....
I had tried for that and i am getting barcode 8/12 digits number and type for that barcode

Comment: You can implement it in your project.

Comment: From that number i want product details....

Comment: Yes you can get details of particular barcode.

Comment: It will returns informations from that barcode. Just check Zxing scanner.

Comment: Do you have that code or link to download source code...??? thanks...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36586/discussion-between-hardy-and-apk)